# Liferay 7 - ADT for single blog item

Tags: java, liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I created an ADT template for list of blogs entries, and it's working fine.
But now I need to custom template for single blog entry, and the problem is that it is used the same ADT for list and single blog because they're associated to same portlet Blogs.

Is there any mode to customize template for single blog entry, using always the portlet Blogs ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Comment: @thunder413 no, after I was busy with other Liferay functions and I wasn't able to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure you are using the Asset Publisher, then create a new content item like a blog entry, then create and attach a structure and a template to it. This is somewhat tricky.

Comment: But which is the difference using the Blogs portlet and the Asset publisher portlet ? With the first is possible to custom the single blog entry ? Now I'm using the Blogs portlet with ADT template.